# Jquery- How to get the same number in two nth-child tags?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, css-selectors

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $(".rain:nth-child(" + (i++) + ")").click(function() {
        $("li:nth-Child(" + (i++) + ")").css("opacity", "1");
        });
       }
```

I have 2 tags, `li` and `img`, with the classname 'rain'.

My Purpose :
When i click third image in rain class, i want to get the third text in `li` tag.

Comment: Read how the [`++` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment) works

Comment: Welcome to SO. In the future please produce a minimal example. That means removing all the stuff that doesn't directly contribute to your question, ie the css stuff. Otherwise, great beginning question.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you each rain image's corresponding `li` element text in the variable `textYouWant`

```
$('img.rain').click(v => {
    var i = $('img.rain').index(v);
    var textYouWant = $('li.rain').eq(i-1).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing your counter variable more than needed. In this case, it should only be incremented in the for loop's increment expression.

The following code should fix this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $(".rain:nth-child(" + (i) + ")").click(function() {
    $("li:nth-Child(" + (i) + ")").css("opacity", "1");
  });
}
```